# Screen Flickers when Updating Widget at Top Level

Tags: flutter

I wrapped my entire app in a StateContainer so that I can read and write certain variables from anywhere within the app.

**main.dart**

```
void main() {
  return runApp(new StateContainer(child: new MyApp()));
}
```

**StateContainer:**

```
class StateContainer extends StatefulWidget { 
  final Widget child;
  final User user;

  StateContainer({
    @required this.child,
    this.user,
  });

  static StateContainerState of(BuildContext context) {
    return (context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<UserData>()).data;
  }

  @override
  StateContainerState createState() => new StateContainerState();
}


class StateContainerState extends State<StateContainer> {
  User user;

  void updateUUID({uuid}) {
    if (user == null) {
      user = new User(uuid);
      setState(() {
        user = user;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        user.uuid = uuid ?? user.uuid;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new UserID(
      data: this,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  } 
}

class User {
  String uuid;
  User(this.uuid);
}

class UserData extends InheritedWidget {
  final StateContainerState data;

  UserData({
    Key key,
    Widget child,
    @required this.data,
  }) : super(
          key: key,
          child: child,
        );

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedWidget oldWidget) {
    return true;
  }

}
```

I'm confused about why the screen flickers when I call updateUUID from the build method of a child, like this:

```
final container = StateContainer.of(context);
container.updateUUID('1234');
```

However, I can read from the StateContainer without causing flickering, like this:

```
var uuid = container.user.uuid;
```

Is there a way I can prevent this screen flickering while still being able to read/write variables from anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution using Provider (ChangeNotifierProvider and Consumer), as described here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

This prevents screen flickering.

If you see an error like

> Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this Consumer Widget

Try moving Provider / ChangeNotifierProvider higher in your widget tree. I had to move mine to the very top to prevent this error even though it already seemed to be above the widgets consuming it.